# CSS [DIV-Tableless] Stack vertically with different heights filling the gaps?

Tags: css, css-float, html

I have different DIVS floating to left (float:left) that have different heights.
I need to stack this divs like image attached:

http://www.krazy.es/images-stackov/capture-divs.jpg

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `DIV` with "**container 5**" has a `clear:left;` or `clear:both;` set in the CSS.

**Edit**

Nevermind, you have all your divs floated left.  Here's some sample code:

[Sample Code on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/hauPq/)

If you play with the width of the window, you'll notice that the divs will attempt to fill up all the available horizontal space.  The messiness you are seeing results from the divs having different vertical heights.  You would get the desired results if:

1. [They all had the same height](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt3PW/) (i.e. they all had 2 lines of text)
2. [You assigned a height value to each div with `height:90px;`](http://jsfiddle.net/D8hBE/) (set it to the largest common denominator)
3. Or [you decided to only have 3 columns of divs max](http://jsfiddle.net/mcHLA/), even if the browser window is wide enough to accommodate more.  They you can put container 1, 2, & 3 in one div on top, and container 4, 5, & 6 in another div underneath
4. Finally (for completeness), [you can put container 1 & 4 in a div, container 2 & 5 in a div, and container 3 & 6 in a div, and then float those divs left](http://jsfiddle.net/pMBsR/).  This would also give you 3 columns, but it's too restrictive, and I don't recommend it ([you can also set the height on the floated divs for better alignment](http://jsfiddle.net/9QtEd/)).

**Option #2 is my favorite.**

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for the answer.

Really the examples you put not making the same think I desire.

I want to stack de DIVS as the same way of image I attach.

No gaps and in asymetric way, making HEIGHT AUTO in all DIVS.

Thanks anyway.

CoolBurn.

Answer (score 0):

Container 1,2,5, and 6 should be in a div, and container 3 and 4 should be in a div. Float THOSE divs.

Comment: Stefan, thanks for the answer, but this DIVS are generated dinamically via PHP and I can't embeed divs into other divs.

Thanks again for response.

Comment: What you said doesn't make any sense.